# States/Layer comps/Frames of a symbol in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have complex symbol, which can (imaginary) exist in different states.

For example, in treeview control node can be either expanded or collapsed, which means different indication.

I want to have one symbol/prototype, but multiple instances of it in different states.

Is it possible in Illustrator?

**UPDATE**

Rephrasing the question: are all instances of the symbol obliged to be identical to it's prototype in Illustrator?

This is not true in programming: a class instance can differ from prototype by field values. For example, different instances of a vector can have different coordinates.

So, for example, can I have a symbol for tree view indicator, which can be in two states, expanded and collapsed, like here

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Your question is pretty unclear, do you think you could attach a screenshot of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible.

With the discontinuation of Fireworks by Adobe, there is now no Adobe product which offers "states" for objects/layers/elements. Illustrator has never had the ability to apply states to objects. I, for one, wish it did.